# How to make textview scrollable in a relative layout? Android

Tags: android

I have an app which has a relative layout as the parent, a header and a footer, and textview as its content (where details are). I'd like to make the textview scrollable. Even though I added scrollview in my xml it's not showing the scrollview.. Can you help me figure out what I'm missing here?

Kindly check my .xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

 <include layout="@layout/tabsfordiseases"/>
 </LinearLayout>


 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/tvValvularDescription"
 style="@style/DescriptionHeader"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
 android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/note16"
 android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <include layout="@layout/zooming_controls" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/tvValvularDescription"
   android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >

  <!--     <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal" > -->

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/tvValvularDescriptionContainer"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="hello world" />

 </ScrollView>



 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TextView` will become scrollable as soon as it exceeds the boundaries of your `ScrollView`, given that you wrapped it in one.

Since you set the text to 'Hello world', I'm guessing the TextView simply doesn't exceed the `ScrollView`..?

Comment: yeah it's set to hello world, but when I click to zoom it in my zoom controls(in the form of imageview) it won't show the scroll view

Answer (score 1):

Put the TextView inside ScrollView to be able to scroll